# Is it normal to sweat while walking (even when it's cold outside)?

Tags: sweat, walking

It's autumn, and the temperature is like 8°C outside. I walk to my office everyday, it's about 10 minutes distance, my speed is a little bit faster than leisure walk.

I wear a T, a sweater and a light jacket outside. While walking, I feel like I am sweating a bit, and when I arrive at office, it's a bit sticky, not so wet, but sticky than usual for this temperature. I take off my jacket and sweater to cool down about 5 minutes, and it is normal again.

Is it normal to sweat like that under that temperature?

Comment: Well, apparently it is.

Comment: there are non thermoregulatory causes of sweating.

Comment: This question should be reworded to something like, "Why do people sometimes sweat when the outside temperature is extremely low?" and made more general. We're not hear to diagnose your personal problems.